# The use of do and does as an auxilliary verb?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

1) All of these things doesn't give me an excuse to run away?
2) All of these things doesn't gives me an excuse to run away?

3) All of these things don't *gives* me an excuse to run away?
4) All of these things don't *give* me an excuse to run away?au

Which among the above is correct? I'm confused between when to use do and when to use does. And if we say that do is used with plural subjects and does for singular subjects, then how to treat the main verb of the sentence? The main verb should be singular or plural?

Comment: *All of these things **are** bad excuses*. A noun phrase like *all of these things* is ***plural***, so it needs the plural verb form ***don't***, not singular ***doesn't***. And we only inflect *one* verb form in a "compound" verb construction including "do-support" such as ***do [not] give***. The other (main) verb (***give***, here) must just be a "bare infinitive" (without the "infinitive marker" ***to***).

Comment: Thanks for the help. So do you mean that the other (main) verb will always be plural irrespective of whether we use 'do' or 'does'?

Comment: ***NO!*** - the other (main) verb will always be an ***INFINITIVE*** form, irrespective of whether we use 'do' or 'does'. It just so happens that for most verbs, the "plural" form *(we give, they give)* is the same as the ("bare" or "unmarked") infinitive, (***to give***, but without ***to***).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has solved so many doubts for me. But do you know of an example where the "plural" form is not the same as unmarked infinitive?

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have said "unmarked infinitive" and "present tense plural" are the same for ***most*** verbs! The ***only*** exception I can think of is ***to be***. Hence *We **are** happy* and *We will **be** happy*, not *We will are happy*. But you must understand that *like most native speakers* I wouldn't have been "taught" things like this in school - we learnt how to speak basic "normal" English in the home, long before we started school (it's only obscure details like whether to write ***learnt*** or ***learned*** there that we might be "taught" later).